# How to make css3 selector :target work in Internet Explorer (IE9 - 11)?

Tags: css, cross-browser, internet-explorer-11

I'm using css selector ":target" to change background color of HTML elements if URL has a hash that matches those elements (see css code below). This works in modern browsers except in IE (tested version 9 to 11 on Windows 8.1). In IE the rule doesn't kick in on first page load, but does if I refresh the page. Is this a bug in IE? Is there a simple solution for it?

```
:target {
    background: yellow;
}
```

Comment: @w3fools says its supported in IE-9 and IE-11 http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_target.asp.

Comment: This problem proved to be caused by use of Modernizr. More info here: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/1577